# \n in UILabel not working

Tags: ios, swift, uilabel

My server return some text contain `\n`. I expect `\n` to print a new line but it does not work. Swift just printed the text and `\n` too. But if I declare string on my local place, e.g.

```
let test = "This is a \nbook"
```

It works! Swift and `UILabel` prints a new line, e.g.

```
This is a

book
```

Then my code i set

```
myLabel.numberOfLines = 0
```

It doesn't work as expected, but the local variable works.

I don't understand why though.

[image]

Comment: can you please post the example text you are trying to print here? So it can be tested with the same code

Comment: Did the server perhaps return \\n ? That explains why it is printing \n

Answer (score 1):

Try this on the string which you get from the server:

```
saleDescription["description"].string!.replacingOccurrences(of: "\\n", with: "\n")
```

Answer (score -1):

```
myLabel.numberOfLines = -1
```

Making myLabel numberOfLines = -1 means "infinite" lines. I hope this helps.

Comment: it's not work. if print or set it on UILabel .it always print "\n"

Comment: @SakonlapakPetcharayuttapan your approach it is correct. To allow multiple lines you need to set it to ZERO https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UILabel_Class/#//apple_ref/occ/instp/UILabel/numberOfLines

Comment: @SakonlapakPetcharayuttapan make sure your label frame has enough room to display all lines

Comment: @LeoDabus I has enough room to show all line. If i receive text from my server .It's always print /n in log and UILabel but if i declare a same text in local place . it works and show a new line for me

Comment: @LeoDabus I tried to use that method then my string from server didn't split   \n to array but it change \n to \\n in array[0]

Comment: @SakonlapakPetcharayuttapan How would you expect someone to help you with such a complex string if you post it in a screenshot

Answer (score -1):

When you have such a case, use a `UITextView` instead of `UILabel`

Comment: For who downvoted, the textview was the only solution for this case. I was getting data from the server and while populating the text in UILabel the \n was not returning.